# How can I create canvas the same size as a div in a grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to create a page that has a grid layout, and I'm facing some issues when I try to put a smaller canvas inside one of the grid's div's. The main issue is that I cannot get the height of the parent div, which would be the first step.

That's and example of the code, I've tried a couple of things, but the height comes back as undefined. Also, is there a better way to achieve this layout? I'm very sorry if there are any mistakes.

```
.all-grid{
 width:80%; /*I've also tried switching these to px*/
 height: 100%;
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: 50% 5% 15% 30%;
 grid-template-rows: 5% 15% 40% 10% 25% 5%;}

.header{
 grid-row: 1/2;
 grid-column: 1/5;}

.yellow{
background-color: yellow;
grid-row: 2/3;
grid-column: 1/2;}

.orange{
background-color: orange;
grid-row: 4/5;
grid-column: 1/3;}
```

```
let canvas;
let ctx;
const start=()=>{
...
canvas.width = $(".header").width(); /*undefined, tried using document.querySelector(".header") as well*/
canvas.height = $(".header").height(); /*undefined*/
```

```
<div class="header">
 <canvas></canvas>
</div>
...
```

Comment: P.S. I haven't included all off the grid elements, but there are more blocks in the grid, they are different heights and widths, that's why I need those percentages

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the JQuery selector for the `canvas` element like this:

```
canvas = $('canvas').get(0);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let canvas;
let ctx;
const start = () => {
  //...
  console.log($(".header").width());
  canvas = $('canvas').get(0);
  canvas.width = $(".header").width();
  console.log(canvas.width);
  canvas.height = $(".header").height();
  console.log(canvas.height);
}

start();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.all-grid {
  width: 80%;
  /*I've also tried switching these to px*/
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 5% 15% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 5% 15% 40% 10% 25% 5%;
}

.header {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/5;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```